# Angular 2 - Injectable() decorator

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I don't completely understand the `@Injectable` decorator in Angular 2. Even though I do not use it, service works. (Look at below examples)

What is the purpose of using `@Injectable` decorator?

Below are two examples, one with and one without `Injectable` with respective plunker examples:

With @Injectable [Example1](https://plnkr.co/edit/gSilw5Qxj8W6ErCybk39?p=preview) `

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  get():any[]{
    return "something"
}
```

Without @Injectable [Example2](https://plnkr.co/edit/9S8CRArrZm8cfQhLKrdB?p=preview)

```
export class AppService{
  get():any[]{
    return "something"
}
```

Of course I know the reason of using `@Injectable` decorator, for Dependency injection, but like i said before, I don't understand completely. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injectable is not required, if the service doesn't have constructor parameters. It's considered to add it to all services anyway, because it's a common mistake that later parameters are added but the `@Injectable()` decorator is forgotten because it was working before.